# Translate camera horizontally and vertically with the arrow keys in WebGL

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am implementing a simple movement of the camera in WebGL javascript with the keyboard, in X and Y axes.
The problem is that the camera moves in the world coordinates, not the X and the Y of the camera, so it is not a real feeling and the movement changes depending on the camera orientation.

Here is some code (I don#t think the updateprojectionmatrix is necessary here:

```
var arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
    var delta = 100;
    switch (event.which) {
        case arrow.left:
            camera.position.x = camera.position.x - delta;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            break;
        case arrow.up:
            camera.position.y = camera.position.y + delta;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            break;
        case arrow.right:
            camera.position.x = camera.position.x + delta;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            break;
        case arrow.down:
            camera.position.y = camera.position.y - delta;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to move depending on the camera rotation? For instance, when pressing the up key, it should move in the direction it is facing? In that case you will have calculate the x and y components yourself using trigonometry (unless WebGL got something built-in for that, I don't know anything about that)

Comment: Yes that is what I want, I think THREE.js must have something to handle it easily. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using three.js, try this [OrbitControls example](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this article on cameras in WebGL](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html)

It shows that a look at matrix, which is what a camera is, is computed like this

```
+----+----+----+----+
| Xx | Xy | Xz |  0 |  <- x axis
+----+----+----+----+
| Yx | Yy | Yz |  0 |  <- y axis
+----+----+----+----+
| Zx | Zy | Zz |  0 |  <- z axis
+----+----+----+----+
| Tx | Ty | Tz |  1 |  <- camera position
+----+----+----+----+
```

So, you should be able to move the camera along it's current view plane by adding the camera's world x axis and/or y axis to its position.

In three.js this would work

```
  var arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
  var delta = 0.05;
  var xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[0], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[1], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[2]);
  var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[4], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[5], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[6]);

  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case arrow.left:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(xAxis, -delta);
      break;
    case arrow.up:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(yAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.right:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(xAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.down:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(yAxis, -delta);
      break;
  }
```

Working sample:

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.125);
directionalLight.position.set( 1, 2, 0.5 );

directionalLight.position.normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

camera.position.x = 1;
camera.position.y = 0.75;
camera.position.z = 1.5;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

function render() {
  resize();  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
  var delta = 0.05;
  var xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[0], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[1], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[2]);
  var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[4], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[5], 
      camera.matrixWorld.elements[6]);
  
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case arrow.left:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(xAxis, -delta);
      break;
    case arrow.up:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(yAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.right:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(xAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.down:
      camera.position.addScaledVector(yAxis, -delta);
      break;
  }
});
                        
function resize() {
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  var width = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}
```

```css
html, body, canvas {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r74/three.min.js"></script>
```

Three.js also has a `translateOnAxis` function so you can do this

```
var arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
var delta = 0.05;
var xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case arrow.left:
      camera.translateOnAxis(xAxis, -delta);
      break;
    case arrow.up:
      camera.translateOnAxis(yAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.right:
      camera.translateOnAxis(xAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.down:
      camera.translateOnAxis(yAxis, -delta);
      break;
  }
});
```

Working sample:

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.125);
directionalLight.position.set( 1, 2, 0.5 );

directionalLight.position.normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

camera.position.x = 1;
camera.position.y = 0.75;
camera.position.z = 1.5;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

function render() {
  resize();  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();

var arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
var delta = 0.05;
var xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case arrow.left:
      camera.translateOnAxis(xAxis, -delta);
      break;
    case arrow.up:
      camera.translateOnAxis(yAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.right:
      camera.translateOnAxis(xAxis, delta);
      break;
    case arrow.down:
      camera.translateOnAxis(yAxis, -delta);
      break;
  }
});
                        
function resize() {
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  var width = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}
```

```css
html, body, canvas {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r74/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I realized that the center of rotation of the camera  does not change when moving with the keyboard. This is defined by:

`controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

function Center(pos) {
    controls.center.x = pos.x;
    controls.center.y = pos.y;
    controls.center.z = pos.z;
}`